# Set DataContext in the logic tree in WPF Blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I have a question regarding the Data Context of a Window and how it is inherited by the children controls.

If I have a Window, whose `DataContext` property is set in XAML like such:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SomeViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

By adding a user control to the window, I understand that the user control will have its data context inherited from the window (unless I specify otherwise).

```
<local:MyUserControl />
```

What about within the user control? Since it is a different XAML file, how can I strongly type the Data Context within the user control? So if I specify a data context within the control:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:SomeViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Does that override the Window's instance of the view model, creating a new instance in memory? I assume it does and if so, how can I pass around a view model to children views via xaml? I know I can do it in code-behind with direct assignments but I want this to be handled in xaml.

We've segregated the majority of our UI and currently have to manually assign the context in code behind.

I tried using `RelativeSource` but it did not seem to work. Perhaps I was using it wrong, but the context was never passed around.

Any thoughts?

**Update 1**

To clarify, I present a simple Window with a DataContext set to a custom view model.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyCustomView">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ProjectViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <views:MyCustomView />
    </StackPanel>
<Window>
```

Now within my `MyCustomView` user control, the other developer working on it will not know what the Type of the Data Context is with out manually walking through all of the possible parent Window's to see where it is being used. What I would like, is within my UserControl, to do the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.DiaryDetailsDescription"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >

<UserControl.DataContext Type="viewModels:ProjectViewModel />

</UserControl>
```

So that the designer/developer working on that user control knows that the data context for that user control will be the `ProjectViewModel` type, inherited by the owning Window.

**Update 2**

So to further clarify, what I want to do in my User Control XAML is the equivalent to the following C# code.

```
return (SingleViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

So the Designer in Blend knows exactly what type the DataContext will be. To him, the DataContext is just an object in the user control, even though it inherits the `SingleViewModel` context from the Window.

Comment: `how can I pass around a ViewModel to children views via xaml?` - Could you write in detail about it?

Comment: If it gets inherited by default then what's the need to pass it manually?

Comment: The issue is that the user control doesn't know the type of the data context. It makes intelli sense worthless and difficult to code. If I can strongly type the context in the user control xaml, using the parent Type it would be nice.

Comment: The other reason is need this is for designers and other developers. If I add the control to the main window then I know what the context will be. If another developer discovers a layout issue and opens up the control xaml to fix it, there won't be anything strongly typed to let him/her know what Type the context is.

Comment: I added additional clarification at @Anatoliy's request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use a bunch `DataTemplate + UserControl`? In Resources e.g. in Window create `DataTemplate` with your UserControl:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SingleViewModel}">
        <vw:SingleView /> <!-- Your UserControl -->
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And in root Panel add the `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent"  
                Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" />
```

*Where CurrentViewModel may be SingleViewModel type.*

In this case, we see immediately that for *`SingleView`* DataContext using `vm:SingleViewModel` type. For more info, see [`this`](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/wpf-applying-data-templates-dynamically-in-contentcontrol/) and [`this`](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/).

**`Edit: more suitable option`**

You can also try use [`d:DesignInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490796%28VS.100%29.aspx):

> Use `d:DesignInstance` for create data bindings at design time for a DataContext that is assigned at run time. To create the data binding, you use the data binding builder to create a special design-time data context and set the DesignInstance to a business object type. `DesignInstance` is a design-time property.

It is used successfully in the Blend for assigning DataContext. `d:DesignInstance` provides a technique for creating a non-faux type, setting the property `IsDesignTimeCreatable` to *True* on the d:DesignInstance enables this.

For more information, please see this:

[`d:DesignInstance, d:DesignData in Visual Studio 2010 Beta2`](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/)

Comment: I'm not sure using a ContentControl is what I'm looking for. Maybe it is; this allows me to instance a View based on the ViewModel associated with the current Window. I have that in place already. My issue is, how can I strongly type the data context within my custom User Control XAML, so the designer (in Blend) know's what the data context Type is. While still using the inherited data context from the window?

Comment: So in your example, the `vw:SingleView` user control is used for the `SingleViewModel`, but the `vm:SingleView` user control XAML does not know that it's DataContext is strongly typed to `vm:SingleViewModel`. This is the issue I'm trying to solve. So a Designer using Blend will know what the actual data context of the custom user control is, without having to crawl his way through all of the Window's that might use that control, reading the XAML.

Comment: @Johnathon Sullinger: Maybe you fit [`DesignInstance DataContext`](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/)?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Anatoliy! Can you add that link to your answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: @Johnathon Sullinger: Yes, I added this link to my answer, please see my edit.